# Check what Type of Enum came into the Generic Method

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I want to now check the incoming column to see what type of enum it is and based on that, Im returning the correct DB type for the column.  I can't get this to work, not sure how to:

```
  public DbType GetColumnDbType<T>(T column) where T: IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
        {
            if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) throw new ArgumentException("the object passed in must an enum type");


            switch (column)
            {
                case (Enums.MemberColumn)column: 
                    switch (Enums.MemberColumn)
                    {
                        case Enums.MemberColumn.Address1:
                            return DbType.String;
                            break;
                        case Enums.MemberColumn.City:
                            return DbType.String;
                            break;
                        case Enums.MemberColumn.State:
                            return DbType.String;
                            break;
                    }
            }
   .....
```

UPDATED

here's what I tried but the compiler is complaining on the first line saying "Value of Integral Type expected"

```
    switch(typeof(T))
    {
        case (typeof (Enums.MemberColumn)):
            switch ((Enums.MemberColumn) column)
            {
                case Enums.MemberColumn.Address1:
                    return DbType.String;
                    break;
                case Enums.MemberColumn.City:
                    return DbType.String;
                    break;
                case Enums.MemberColumn.State:
                    return DbType.String;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported enum type.", "MemberColumn");
                    break;
            }
    }
```

Comment: If you are switching based on type, you should really consider making type specific overloads.

Comment: As I pointed out below, you cannot switch on an expression of type `Type`. From the compiler: "A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type".

Comment: Please do not vote to close this.  I'm asking in the end how to get this working with generics.  There is always debate, put that aside whoever wanted to close this.  We're still all focused on THE question I asked originally, that has not changed focus.

Comment: So then there's really no way to do what I'm trying to do then right Mike?  I mean other than typeof(T) in my switch, trying to think another way to do this in my switch with that enum value coming into this generic method..

Answer (score 3):

Your switch statement seems a little funny to me. Try this instead:

```
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Enums.MemberColumn))
        {
            switch ((Enums.MemberColumn)column)
            {
                case Enums.MemberColumn.Address1:

         ....
```

As others have suggested, what's the point of having a generic method if you are going to be switching based on its type? Just do this instead:

```
public DbType GetColumnDbType(Enums.MemberColumn column)
{
     switch(column)
     {
         case (Enums.MemberColumn.Address1):

         ....

}
```

And then just create another overloaded method for the other enum types:

```
public DbType GetColumnDbType(Enums.OtherMemberColumn column)
{
     switch(column)
     {
          .....
     }

}
```

Or...the way I would do it:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class DbTypeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public DbType DbType { get; private set; }

    public DbTypeAttribute(DbType dbType)
    {
        this.DbType = dbType;
    }
}

public static class DbHelper<T> where T : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible, struct
{
    private static Dictionary<long, DbType> _dbTypeLookup = CreateLookup();

    public static DbType GetColumnType(T column)
    {
        return _dbTypeLookup[(long)(object)column];
    }

    private static Dictionary<long, DbType> CreateLookup()
    {   
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("T must be an enum type.");

        var dbTypeLookup = new Dictionary<long, DbType>();

        foreach (var name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(T)))
        {
            var enumMember = typeof(T).GetMember(name).Single();
            var dbTypeAttr = (DbTypeAttribute)enumMember.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DbTypeAttribute), false).Single();

            dbTypeLookup.Add((long)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), name), dbTypeAttr.DbType);
        }

        return dbTypeLookup;
    }
}
```

With the above code, I can now do this:

```
public enum MemberColumn
{
    [DbType(DbType.String)] Address1,
    [DbType(DbType.String)] Address2,
    [DbType(DbType.String)] FirstName,
    [DbType(DbType.String)] LastName,
    [DbType(DbType.DateTime)] DateOfBirth,
}


// ... later, in some method somewhere:

MemberColumn c = MemberColumn.Address1;

DbType dbType = DbHelper<MemberColumn>.GetColumnType(c); // sets dbType to DbType.String
```

Comment: You cannot switch on an expression of type `Type`

Comment: thanks I'm not that great with Generics yet...which is why it's so funky :)

Comment: "As others have suggested, what's the point of having a generic method if you are going to be switching based on its type"  because this is a utility method where I am sending in Table columns to get back the associated DbType back.  This method will be like a catch all, will find the right case statement based on the type of Enum sent in originally.

Comment: also I don't want a ton of overloads, my class is gonna get very long for this.  I thought having a generic method with a bunch of case statements might be easier to read and maintain.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict IMHO, overloads are much more readable and maintainable, but pick whatever you and your team feels is appropriate.

Comment: oh whoops Mike is saying you can't do a switch on typeof(T)

Comment: I do like overloads, but in this specific case I don't see the need to overload, I just want to pass in an enum value and have it spit back out the DbType and instead of so many method declarations in this situation, it's much less code (no method sigs needed for each overload)

Comment: so I still can't get this to work via my latest update.  Because you can't switch on an expression of Type like Mike stated...

Comment: Right, just change the outer switch to an if block.

Comment: You are trading a simple to understand method signature to a block of if statements that look like this: if (typeof(T) == typeof(Enums.MemberColumn)), followed by a cast to that type. The compiler can statically determine which method to call at compile time and avoid the cast if you use method overloads, which will be faster and easier to maintain (want to see how it is determining a DbType? Right click => Go To Definition and it will jump to the proper method with only the relevant enum switches).

Comment: I'll add one more option to this that is more maintainable than this hot mess of stuff in a min.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't switch on an expression of type `Type`, you can structure the method like this:

```
public DbType GetColumnDbType<T>(T column) where T: IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible, struct // Note you can add struct constraint here as well.
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) throw new ArgumentException("the object passed in must an enum type");

    var type = typeof(T);
    if (t == typeof(Enums.MemberColumn))
    {
       switch((Enums.MemberColumn)column)
       {
              // case statements
       }
    }
    else if (t == typeof(Enums.OtherColumn))
    {
    }
    else
    {
       throw new NotSupportedException();
    }       

}
```

However, I think that overloads for each `enum` type would be more readable and maintainable. If there is other metadata you need to associate with each `enum` value I think a better design would use objects. You could give the objects enum like semantics by making singletons:

```
public class MemberColumn
{
    private MemberColumn(DbType columnType) { ColumnType = columnType; }

    public DbType ColumnType { get; private set; }

    private readonly static MemberColumn _address1 = new MemberColumn(DbType.String);
    public static Address1 { get { return _address1; } }

    private readonly static MemberColumn _city = new MemberColumn(DbType.String);
    public static City { get { return _city; } }

    private readonly static MemberColumn _state = new MemberColumn(DbType.String);
    public static State { get { return _state; } }

}
```

Sample usage:

```
DbType addressColumnType = MemberColumn.Address1.ColumnType;
```

Probably the only thing lacking now is converting the objects to unique string representations which could be easily added.

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up using 'if' instead of 'switch' in this type of case (nice pun me * pat on own back *).  The switch/case control is essentially a nice way of handling a list of possible equality cases and was introduced in order to reduce repeated code.  However, if you aren't comparing a compatible type, then it's simply back to the old method:

```
var memberColumnEnum = column as Enums.MemberColumn
if(memberColumnEnum != null)
{
    switch (memberColumnEnum)
    {
        case Enums.MemberColumn.Address1:
            return DbType.String;
        case Enums.MemberColumn.City:
            return DbType.String;
        case Enums.MemberColumn.State:
            return DbType.String;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported enum type.", "MemberColumn");
    }
}
```